# How do I do Drag-and-Drop with an Appindicator?

Tags: indicator, programming

Is it possible to connect the Appindicator Icon to receive a basic drop-event?

Like with every other GTK+ Widget `drag_dest_set(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope.  You can only receive menu open events.

Comment: Good to know, sad though. Thanks!